# Use typescript class in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been going around the block in circles and just wanted an easy example of how I could use a typescript class in a javascript function.

My motivation is to use a typescript constant in a legacy js file (the js file can't be converted to ts yet, hence my dilemma).

I've read that **.ts** code should be somehow built in the process for us to be able to use it in **.js**, but everything has been a bit convoluted.

Example **.ts** class:

```
export class ExampleConstantsClass { static readonly exampleConst = 1; }
```

Now I'd like to import this in a **.js** file and use it for example like this:

```
function exampleFunction() { return ExampleConstantsClass.exampleConst }
```

Comment: The first code looks like a javascript to me

Comment: @KonradLinkowski `readonly`?

Comment: nor readonly, nor const can't be used in .js files. Truly, how the code looks doesn't really matter in this case. It is there for an easy example. I would like to use that class in .js file.

Comment: @Zigzagas .. what did the OP try so far?

Comment: I've tried blindly importing it, declare the code in a module and then using it, but to no avail.

Comment: What if you build your TS file to a JS file using `tsc`, then you could `import` the resulting JS file.

Comment: @Kokodoko I don't have experience with that, but I'll see what can be done. Don't know exactly how to tell my builder to make these decisions, but we'll see.

Comment: @Kokodoko If `const` can't be used, `import` can't be used as well, seem like `ES5` to me

Comment: `tsc` is a simple program that converts TS to JS. You run in in the terminal. The simplest way to use it: open terminal in the correct folder and type `tsc myfile.ts`. It will generate the `.js` file for you. You can get more options by adding a `tsconfig.json` file in your folder. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code usually can't be run as typescript. At some point it has to be compiled into JS in order to be run. Depending on your compiler settings you could maybe even just import from the compiled JS-file into your native JS file.

```
yourJSFile.js
tsFile.js (this is the file the compiler generates)

tsFile.ts (this is your ts file you write in)
```

you now just import from `tsFile.js` into `yourJSFile.js` (you need to compile your TS code anyways, otherwise you won't be able to actually run it)

As the comments pointed out, tsc is the compiler you usually use for Typescript. (There are tons of tutorials on how to do a basic tsc setup) - But may I ask how you managend to use TS without a compiler until now?

Comment: The tsconig.ts is being used alright. It's just that I don't have a lot of knowledge about this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile your .ts code to a .js es6 module with this setup. Create a `tsconfig.json` file with these contents:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Then open a terminal in your project folder and type `tsc`.

Comment: whats being used in my project, is as follows: `target: es5, module: amd`